# What is the rule with Locathahs and Dhampirs? Can it bypass the water breathing?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, racial-traits

I am planning on making a Locathah, and I found the Dhampir subrace/liniage. And by default, and Dhampir has "Deathless Nature. You don't need to breathe." But Locathahs have the trait of "Limited Ambhibiousness. You can breathe air and water, but you need to be submerged at least once every 4 hours to avoid suffocating."

The thing that I'm asking about is if Deathless nature overrides Limited Amphibiousness. It says that they SUFFOCATE which alludes to breathing,and the deathless nature makes them unneeded to breath. So does making a Locathah a Dhampir override the limited air breathing?

Comment: I’ve added the [dnd-5e] tag since you mentioned several 5e features.

Answer (score 5):

### The Locathah’s Limited Amphibiousness trait is totally replaced by the Dhampir traits.

The ancestral legacy trait states:

> If you replace a race with this lineage, **you can keep the following elements of that race**: any skill proficiencies you gained from it and any climbing, flying, or swimming speed you gained from it.

The Locathah’s Limited Amphibiousness trait is not on this list, so a Dhampir does not keep any part of that trait.